# Complex Count in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am beginner in SQL and I have a question for an exercise.

I have a table "movies" . The columns are title and year.

The question is: **How many movies came out in each year?**

I have to give the shortest query. What do you advise?

Thanks ! :)

PS: I use MySQL

Comment: If you need help with this question, then learn SQL:  pick up a book, read an on-line tutorial, sign-up for a Coursera course, or something similar.

Comment: you should use [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause in mysql.  Do not post such type of homework questions.

Comment: wow so complex!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how:

```
select count(*) as movies_count, year from movies group by year
```

Comment: There was no added text and the code was not in the code block before edit by M. Arendsen  :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select
year,
count(*)
from movies
group by year
order year desc
```